# Does it make sense to still use firewire?

Tags: macbook-pro, desktop, firewire

I have a macbook pro 2012 non-retina which has firewire and a 2007 macbook (a white plastic one) which I use as a local server and it also has firewire. In addition to that I have my desktop PC which is a hackintosh build. I know that firewire is kinda obsolete after apple killed it off but I know that firewire has good speeds and it would be great to use for copying big files (I often do). So does it make sense to invest in a PCI firewire card (for like 10-20€) for my desktop PC so I can copy things with good speeds even though firewire isn't used anymore?

Edit: Just ordered a Firewire PCI-E Card for my Desktop (11€) and a 1.8m Firewire cable (5€). I will let everybody know how it works out once I tested everything out.

Comment: I'd use a crossover gigabit Ethernet cable (or run it through a gigabit Ethernet switch if you have one). It'll be easier and cheaper. Then you can access it as though it's a network drive (though if you're using a crossover Ethernet cable you'll have to assign IP addresses to each computer manually)

Comment: I just spent like 2 hours trying to copy over a 120gb folder directly with a pach ethernet cable and didn't have any success. I heard you dont need crossover cables anymore because of something in network cards that makes it possible with ethernet cables. Under Linux I'm able to copy pc to pc with a patch cable but under macOS I couldnt make it happen and so while googling around I read firewire is a great solution.

Comment: Then I differ to bmike's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have firewire in production still and you can usually get excellent performance / $ by buying older technology.

- The latency of FireWire is excellent - on par with Thunderbolt
- The bandwidth of firewire is nearly that of gigabit ethernet and way faster than any source or destination of data that you will send on that era hardware.
- The reliability of FireWire is excellent

Why spend more for a connection that won't limit your speeds and is very easy on the wallet and reliable? I say go for it unless you really want to spend more on the card and cables or could use gigabit ethernet instead.

Comment: Does FireWire have any advantage over gigabit Ethernet?

Comment: I tried Gigabit ethernet but no success... But I think Firewire is a great way to save some money. I just have one Question, how do I connect multiple machines to each other? With Gigabit ethernet I just use a switch but how do I do it with firewire? Is it only possible to have direct connections or is there something similar to a ethernet switch availible for firewire?

Comment: you can daisy chain firewire. You could use a dual ported hard drive (or drive controller) to chain two devices together and run networking. Sharing the storage isn't generally feasible. There are firewire hubs if you need them, too. @Tanonic

Comment: firewire hubs are pretty expensive tho, like 70€. But I'm still very interested in firewire so I guess I will give it a go. Do you have any experience with firewire PCI cards for desktop PCs? will they work with my hackintosh or are there any specific drivers needed? Also how is firewire Linux support?

Comment: Connecting multiple machines with Firewire just takes a cable.   You can go into Network and make it a TCP/IP channel.  Disks with Firewire connectors, though, don't communicate through TCP/IP... that's only computer-to-computer.